# Will a person experience micro or zero gravity inside an aeroplane in free fall

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Let us say that a person is inside a stationary aeroplane being held by a stationary helicopter in the sky. Now, the cable which supports the aeroplane breaks. Thus the aeroplane is now not bound by anything.

1) Will the person inside the aeroplane experience micro or zero gravity when the aeroplane starts falling?

2) Will he, at any point in time, be pushed to the ceiling of the aeroplane?

3) What will be the answer to the above questions, in case the above scenario happened in vacuum?

Comment: What do you mean in vacuum?

Comment: Related: http://www.gozerog.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cases with the aeroplane in air, at first the person will feel zero gravity, but significant air drag will swiftly prevent the plane from accelerating at $g$. Therefore, the person would feel the force of their seat on their bottom disappear, but very soon afterwards the rider will be forced back into their seat: they will feel a steadily rising force  upwards that asymptotes to the person's weight as the aeroplane approaches its terminal velocity and stops accelerating.

If the plane is dropped in a vacuum, then now the person will feel sustained zero gravity and will not bump against the ceiling unless pushed or if they push off the floor.

Otherwise, the only way the person can hit the ceiling is if the plane begins accelerates downwards at greater than $g$. This can happen if the plane hits a violent downdraught.

For simulated zero gravity in the atmosphere, the plane must fly a powered downwards flight so that its power overcomes air resistance. This of course is done for astronaut training. Look up the vomit comet.

Answer (score 1):

1) will feel zero gravity. The confusion could be that some (including the NASA website) call microgravity to free fall apparent gravity, others to case where gravity is very small, such as in an asteroid. 
2) it depends, if it is on the seat he will now only feel the force of the cushion trying to gain its original shape. That could give him a little push up, but not too strong.